# Is there an operation in some domain that satisfies $x*x*x = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the set $S = \{0,1\} $ under XOR.
It is the case that $ x \oplus x = 0 \ \ \forall x \in S$.
I was wondering if there is a similar operation in some other domain such that
$x*x*x = 0$ for all objects in the domain. Can we possibly generalize this?

Comment: Surely there must be some other restrictions you want to put on the operation; otherwise, the constant operation (with result $0$) qualifies.

Comment: What do you mean by "constant operation" ? And what restrictions do you suggest to make the problem interesting?

Comment: I mean, if $x * y = 0$ for all $x, y$, that trivially satisfies your condition, right?  But I don't think that's what you were looking for.  So I assume you must want some restrictions on the operation that preclude that trivial answer.

Comment: There is another function over $S$ that satisfy this. Let $0*0 = 1$ and $x*y = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_6$, $2+2+2 \mod 6 =0$

Comment: The collection of strictly lower triangular $3 \times 3$ matrices form an algebra which satisfy $x*x*x = 0$. In general, if $A$ is a strictly triangular $n\times n$ matrix, then $A^n = 0$.

Comment: Slightly related example: Let
$$W = \left\{\, \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\x & 1 & 0\\z & y & 1\end{bmatrix} \mid x,y,z \in \mathbb Z_3 \,\right\}.$$ $W$ is a [non-Abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group#Heisenberg_group_modulo_an_odd_prime_p) of order $27$, and every element of $W$ has order $3$. For an Abelian example, take $(\mathbb Z_3)^n$, for any natural number $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is an element in the ring of polynomials $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$, then $a+a+a=0$.  This can be generalized to characteristic $p$, where $p$ is any prime.

Comment: This is the right answer. The example in the OP is an example of the general case.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ ($n \ge 2$), $a+a+\cdots+a$ ($n$ times) is equal to 0.   If the coefficient ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ need not be a field, then $n$ need not be a prime.